# BackboneJS - Router issues - how to get clean URL's

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

ok I have

```
{{#each mainmenu}}
<li>
    <a href="#pages/{{this.url}}"><h2>{{this.name}}</h2></a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

and in my router

```
routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'pages/firstpage' : 'firstpage',
    'pages/secondpage' : 'secondpage',
    'pages/thirdpage' : 'thirdpage'
},
initialize: function () {
   Backbone.history.start({pushState: false});
}
```

and my json file is:

```
{
    "name":"First page",
    "id":"1",
    "url":"firstpage"
},
{
    "name":"Second page",
    "id":"2",
    "url":"secondpage"
},
{
    "name":"Third page",
    "id":"3",
    "url":"thirdpage"
}
```

the way it is right now my URL is "#pages/secondpage" - how can i get the URL to display "pages/secondpage" - i tried "pushState:true" which didnt work... then in my mainmenu.js view I added an event:

```
events: {
     'click a.second': 'secondpage'
},

secondpage: function() {
    var secondpageRouter = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = 'pages/secondpage';
    secondpageRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
  }
```

but that didnt work either... when I remove the "#pages/" from the anchor above, I almost get the URL I want "pages/secondpage" - but it says "URL could not be found" after clicking the link. So what's going on here???

Please help anyone?

Comment: `<a href="/pages/{{this.url}}">` combined with `pushState:true` should work.

Comment: unfortunately not :-(

Comment: I think you were close with your last bit of code there, you just needed to add `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @muistooshort that doesn't make sense to me. The whole point of backbone.js is to not have to go back to the server to refresh the page. If you don't `preventDefault()` the link, it will send a `get` request to the server.  [The example here](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/) uses `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @RustyToms: Hmm, forgot about the "make `<a>`s behave sensibly" boiler plate hackery I have buried in my app. That and living server-side for the past six months.

Comment: what broswer do you use? As this is a HTML5 feature, for non-supporting browser, Backbone will fall back to fragment version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that you need to be able to serve these urls from the server if necessary, read the docs here: http://backbonejs.org/#History

Then you need to do at least three things.

First, after you have defined your routers, call `Backbone.history` and make sure pushState is true:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })
```

Second, get rid of all the `#` in your links, like this:

```
<a href="pages/{{this.url}}"><h2>{{this.name}}</h2></a>
```

Third, and this is important, you need to intercept all clicks on local links and prevent their default behavior, which would be to route you to a new page.  This is easy with jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href^='/']", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  RouterNameGoesHere.navigate($(event.target).attr("href"), {trigger: true});
});
```

If you aren't using jQuery, listen to link click events in your views deal with the url in your event handlers. I modified your code to add the `event` argument and `event.preventDefault()`:

```
events: {
  'click a.second': 'secondpage'
},

secondpage: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var secondpageRouter = new Backbone.Router();
  var route = 'pages/secondpage';
  secondpageRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
}
```

[Here is an interesting blog post about this issue](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/)

Comment: The most important bit from the docs: *Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL directly. For full search-engine crawlability, it's best to have the server generate the complete HTML for the page ... but if it's a web application, just rendering the same content you would have for the root URL, and filling in the rest with Backbone Views and JavaScript works fine.*

Comment: Great! that worked! What I noticed is, that when I'm using my localhost with the URL "localhost/projectfolder/projectname" and then click the secondpage-anchor it makes my URL "localhost/pages/secondpage" - how to keep the projectfolder and projectname?

Comment: @SHT, whatever you want in your url should be in your link. You can then spoof the route somehow, but if that is the url you want then you should include it in your routes as well. So `href="projectfolder/pages/{{this.url}}"` and the route would be `/projectfolder/pages/secondpage`, etc.

Comment: And while we are at it, it doesn't make sense to make a new router every time you want to navigate.  Make the router one time, and save it as a global variable.  Then call the global variable when you need the router. That way the back and forward buttons will work. They probably don't work for you as it is, right?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Where to declare that global variable?

Comment: @SHT Here is my code for my Backbone app: `window.AFB = AutoFormBot = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function($rootEl, forms){
    console.log("AutoFormBot initialized");
    AFB.formCollection = new AFB.Collections.Forms(forms);

    new AFB.Routers.FormRouter($rootEl);

    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};`  So it is `AFB.Routers.FormRouter` for me, and I declare it right when I am starting up my app. I only need one router. The `Backbone.history.start()` is what makes the forward and back buttons work.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer. I am new and I could use the rep, and I think this is something that could help others in the future.

Comment: I've read that it kind of depends on server-setup to respond to deep linking? Then how am I supposed to test it on localhost?? (just an open thought)