# Using backbone.js routing with Jekyll

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, jekyll

I am generating a static site using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). I am using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) to do few routings.

Suppose the home page is at `localsite.com`... I am not sure how to generate routes for the following URLs.

```
http://localsite.com/hulk &
http://localsite.com/thor
```

The *hulk* and *thor* are the names to be routed.

and my backbone.js router is as follows:

```
<script>
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ":name": "nameRoute" // should match http://localsite.com/anything-here
        }
    });
    // Initiate the router
    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:nameRoute', function(name) {
        console.log(name);
    })

    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

</script>
```

I am not able to get this working. Is there something I am missing?
Will I be able to do this routing with Jekyll?

My Jekyll's _config.yml has

```
permalink: pretty
```

How do get these routes working?

Are there any other suggestions? My goal is to get a similar routing when hosted on [github pages](http://pages.github.com/).

Comment: Must the url be http://localsite.com/thor, or can it be http://localsite.com#thor ?

Comment: @RustyToms, The URL will only be localsite.com/thor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the routing goes, it is pretty straight forward. The second part is the name of the function that will be called, which should be defined inside your router. So just change your code to this and it should work:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ":name": "nameRoute" // should match http://localsite.com/anything-here
    },

    nameRoute: function(name){
        console.log(name);
    }
});
// Initiate the router
var app_router = new AppRouter;

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

If you run into trouble with pushState and getting rid of the backbone-default hashtags, check out this SO question [BackboneJS - Router issues - how to get clean URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504045/backbonejs-router-issues-how-to-get-clean-urls/20508559#20508559) (particularly important for local links, if you don't want to keep reloading from the server), and here is an example of a site getting rid of their `#`: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/