# Change URL without reloading

Tags: javascript, html

i see sometimes on some sites like facebook or the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/) from google, that by clicking a link the url changes (NOT with **#blah**), but the wohle site doesn't reload. I can use back/forward, so it could't be javascript, i think.

Can anybody say me how to implement that on a site? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses pushState, and it is done using javascript and HTML5 with pushState compatible browsers.  Here is some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

A quote from those docs:

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

> This will cause the URL bar to display
>   http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load
>   bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

The url can be changed in this way, and the new page is rendered using javascript. I do this by using Backbone.js, but there are other tools to do the same thing. It is mostly the same technique as those URLs with `#` in them, except they get rid of the hash. Backbone.js will use a `#` by default, but can be configured to make the URL to appear normal.

Here is a [SO question about how to do this using Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504045/backbonejs-router-issues-how-to-get-clean-urls/20508559#20508559)

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can be achieved is with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). As was said in the above comments, this will use AJAX to get new data to display, and then use javascript to change the content of the page, all without loading a new URL.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers whose not support htmll5 like ie8, you can use the library https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ which emulate the html5  pushstate method.